# jquery check if tab with a particular title already exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to get a code snippet which demonstrates how to check if the tab is already opened.

I need the following functionality:
1.user click a button to add additonal tab
2.check if a tab with these title already exists
3.select existing tab if already exists otherwise add a new tab

Best regards,
Javanus

Comment: We kind-of need to see some HTML for this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var nameToCheck = "SomeNewTabName";
var tabNameExists = false;

$('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i) {
    if (this.text == nameToCheck) {
        tabNameExists = true;
    }
});

if (!tabNameExist){
    //code to insert new tab here
}
```

I'm going with the assumption that you are using jQuery UI tabs here...

Comment: Thank you Dubmun, this works fine. Could you give the example also how to select the tab if already exists?

Comment: @javanus I would just select at the 'li' level instead of 'a' and select into 'a' inside the loop to check  for a name match. Then you should already have the tab you want inside the loop. Just declare a variable above to set to it. I think that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution to select the existing tab is a bit complex. The following line, to be placed just below `tabNameExists = true;`, works fine and is very simple

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs('option', 'active', i);
```